# Trouble creating MSI installer with electron

Tags: python, node.js, windows-installer, electron

Good day everyone,

I am trying to create an MSI installer via electron so that it could take into all of the files in my folder, including the python scripts. The unpack version (win-ia32-unpacked) executable works, but it must run within the project folder, as it depends on all of files within that folder.

This is how my package.json file looks like

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "description": "....",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "main": "main.js",
  "build": {
    "app-bundle-id": "org.test.mytest",
    "app-category-type": "public.app-category.box",
    "mac": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        },
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 150,
          "type": "file"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "title": "Layoverbox app",
      "version": "0.28.999.1",
      "iconUrl": "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "msi": true,
      "authors": "Author"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./start-electron.js",
    "postinstall": "install-app-deps",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist:win32": "./node_modules/.bin/build --platform win32 --arch ia32"
  },
  "author": "Layoverbox Team <jonathan@company.com>",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "keymaster": "^1.6.2",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.5",
    "strip": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron-builder": "^5.26.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.3.3",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

It creates the dist folder with the packed and unpacked folder.
But nothing runs in the packed folder, and no sign of MSI, and I get the following error on the command line.

```
Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Jonathan\.cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-1.4.1\rcedit.exe C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\client\project-name\dist\win-ia32\AppName Setup 0.0.3-ia32.exe --set-version-string CompanyName Team --set-version-string FileDescription Demonstrates spawning Express from Electron and using it to serve content --set-version-string ProductName AppName --set-version-string InternalName AppName --set-version-string LegalCopyright Copyright © 2017 Team --set-version-string OriginalFilename  --set-file-version 0.0.3 --set-product-version 0.0.3
Fatal error: Unable to load file
```

Any help would be appreciated.